# CSS Line, align with social icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to get this line to work correctly but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is what I want:

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<ul>
    <li style="margin-top:0px;"><h2>Follow Us</h2></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i style="color:#00aced;" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i style="color:#3B5998;" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i style="color:#007bb6;" class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i style="color:#dd4b39;" class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i style="color:#FE0883;" class="fa fa-flickr fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i style="color:#bb0000;" class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-2x"></i></a>  </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i style="color:#FA9B39;" class="fa fa-rss-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
#all-section ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#all-section ul:after {
    background-color: #b7b7b7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: if you can provide a fiddle I can better help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```css
#all-section ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

with

```css
#all-section ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zsLh5zna/)